# Setting Decimal Points for Numbers in RDL reports

Tags: reporting-services

How do I set the number field in a RDL file to display up to 8 decimal points?
For eg, 12.34567890 will display as 12.34567890 and 12.34 will display as 12.34 but NOT 12.34000000

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

In the Properties window in BIDS, set the Format property of the report item to be `#.########`

This will display:

- 12.34567891 as 12.34567891
- 12.34000000 as 12.34
- 12.34567890 as 12.3456789

Answer (score 1):

Right Click on the Report Item -> Properties -> Provide the below setting this will set the decimal formatting.

[image: Decimal Format]

Default value is 2 that's why you facing that problem.

Comment: This will set ALL values to 8 d.p. - I think the original poster wanted the number of d.p. to vary depending on the number of trailing zeroes.

Comment: Your answer is correct, up to a point. However, as Mark Bannister points out, if the cell value is 12.34000000 then using that format will display 12.34000000. The #.######## format suggested by Mark will display the values as requested in the question and will also remove the trailing zeroes if any. I think we can infer from the question that this would be desirable.

Comment: Both answers are technically correct, but I am just pointing out that Mark's is more likely to be the one that meets the requirements of the original poster. No need to get offended.

Answer (score 1):

### Numeric Formatting for decimal places that shows maximum 8 non zero digit after decimal point and negative value in brackets

In the property window of selected numeric field, set below value to Format Property,

```
#,0.########;(#,0.########);'(None)'
#,0.########;  <-- Formatting for positive value 
(#,0.########); <-- Formatting for Negative value 
'(None)' <-- Omits negative sign in this case
```

Format property is applicable to Numeric field only

Answer (score 1):

Use the expression **`=Str(NumericField)`** to remove trailing zeros.